# Run build app with React and Gulp

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gulp

I am following the tutorial for React in Lynda.com.
But I can't see the preview in the browser.

Here is the link of the Repo for the files.
https://github.com/planetoftheweb/reactinterface/tree/02_01b

How can I view this in my browser with localhost:8080?
My browser just display the directories.
I am using XAMPP in windows 8.1. Do I need to install something? or configure something?
When I tried viewing localhost/builds/app/index.html,
it is showing but the react is not processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any special web server, like XAMPP, because a browser can interpret your js code itself. You just need to include your compiled js file into your index.

Maybe you will need to add React sources, if you don't use any bundle framework like Webpack or Browserify.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Also, I would recommend read the official tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html).

Comment: I jsut copy the files to XAMPP. so even I don't use XAMPP. It is showing only directories. do I need to do something? run command in windows cmd?

Comment: As I see in your gulpfile you just need to run `gulp` and it's should webserver, and other things itself. No copy to XAMPP needed.

Comment: How can I run gulp? I didnt install anything in my windows.

Comment: By the way, I installed npm, browserify ,gulp,webserver. but still have an error. "module react not found"

Comment: I tried also "npm install --save react react-dom" but there is an error installing. "Refusing to install react as dependency of itself"

Comment: ha, sorry I wasn't here. Glad to help.